# Primefaces Drag&Drop drags and drops only one element from dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

So, I've used example from showcase of PrimeFaces https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/dataTable.xhtml. That's my code:

```
<div class="page_content">
        <div class="header">Очередь рассылок</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleDrop(event, ui) {
                var droppedEmail = ui.draggable;

                droppedEmail.fadeOut('fast');
            }
        </script>
        <h:form>
            <p:fieldset id="availableEmailsField" legend="Доступные рассылки">
                <p:dataTable id="availableEmails" var="email" value="#{emailingQueueUI.customEmails}">
                    <p:column style="width: 20px;">
                        <h:outputText id="dragIcon" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"/>
                        <p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" helper="clone"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{email.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Название">
                        <h:outputText value="#{email.name}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Заголовок">
                        <h:outputText value="#{email.header}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Количество порции">
                        <h:outputText value="#{email.chunkSize}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:fieldset>

            <p:outputPanel id="selectedEmailsField">
                <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
                    <h:outputText value="Переместите сюда c доступных рассылок" rendered="#{empty emailingQueueUI.customEmailQueue}" style="font-size:16px;" />
                    <p:dataTable id="selectedEmails" var="email" value="#{emailingQueueUI.customEmailQueue}" rendered="#{not empty emailingQueueUI.customEmailQueue}"
                                 rowIndexVar="index">
                        <!--<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{emailingQueueUI.onQueueReorder}" update=":form" />-->
                        <p:column headerText="Номер в очереди">
                            <h:outputText value="#{index}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Рассылка">
                            <h:outputText value="#{email.id}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Название">
                            <h:outputText value="#{email.name}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Заголовок">
                            <h:outputText value="#{email.header}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Количество порции">
                            <h:outputText value="#{email.chunkSize}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:droppable for="selectedEmailsField" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availableEmails" onDrop="handleDrop">
                <p:ajax listener="#{emailingQueueUI.onEmailDrop}" update="dropArea availableEmails" />
            </p:droppable>
        </h:form>

    </div>
```

There is a problem with d&d, I can drag and drop only one element from "availableEmailsField". When I try to drop another element it removes previous element and adds the dropped one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your bean.

Make sure that you initialize `customEmailQueue` inside `@PostConstruct` method and use the proper bean scope. In this case `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an update function must be setted correctly in order to work properly. I faced the same issue and discovered that the ajax inside dropable has to update all drag-drop area elements, it seems that this action solves the issue.

The **solution** that worked is to put inside your form an:

```
 <h:panelGroup id="elementsPanel">
   ....
     ...
      ...
     ...
   ....
 </h:panelGroup>
```

, surrounding all drag-drop elements (if you dont want a panelgroup the idea is to update all the components)

and on the dropable update this panel:

```
 <p:droppable id="dropHandler" for="selectedTable" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="myDataSource" onDrop="handleDrop">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{dimensionsClass.onDimensionDrop2}" update="elementsPanel" />
                </p:droppable>
```

I hope that helps!